# how we can restrict user to click or go on the browser window until they close the opened pop up window?

Tags: javascript, popup

I am making a web application which takes the exam related programming languages, and i am opening a pop up window for test when a user click to start a test ,
but i want to restrict them to go on the main broweser window until they submit the exam(pope up window closed automatically) or they will close manualy

Comment: where is the dialog code ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know its not possible with javascript. but cant you better use a box that will lay on top of the original page content like you can do with Jquery.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Removing the buttons and other forms of cancelation and only leave a post button when all answers are given.